# fill height and radius in truncated cone with leakage

Tags: geometry

Assume I have a truncated cone of inclination angle 16 degrees, top radius R = 0.5 metres and base radius r = 0.05 metres 
If I fill in water with mass m = 20 kg, how can I determine the vertical fill height and fill radius?

Next, if I leak out water of known mass m = 2kg (or at rate of 2kg/h), 
how can I determine the decreased water height and radius level based on the mass of water collected?

Comment: What I know is the mass of the water that I collect during the leak. I assume that the mass collected is directly proportional to the height (which I think is wrong!!). I measured the initial height of the water and used the mass decrease ratio to calculate a new height and then radius. I know this doesn't look right since there is a slant and the height decrease will most probably be non-linear

Comment: You are right that this is non-linear, and it's because of the slant. I would figure out what the volume is of the truncated part of the cone, and add that to the calculations. In other words, if the volume of the truncated part is $2cm^2$ (just a guess), then add that, have a whole cone, and say you fill it with $20.02kg$ of water instead. That way, you don't have to think about the truncation at all during any of the calculations, and once you know the height of water in the un-truncated cone, you just truncate back.

Comment: I think you forget that the radius is changing too and this makes the determination of the volume non-trivial

Comment: You should also consider the atmospheric pressure which has an effect on the leak rate in different heights.

Comment: Atmospheric pressure/height in this case plays virtually little/no role considering the system size